# Tutorial on advanced XAML databinding

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

Can someone recommend a good tutorial or video that explains the more advanced XAML data-binding syntax? I understand and use simple binding between my View and ViewModel classes such as:

```
Text="{Binding Name}"
```

But sometimes I see bindings like this on other tutorials and blog posts which I have a hard time following.

```
ToolTip="{Binding Path=AdornedElement.ToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType={x:Type Adorner}}}"
```

Usually I can get things working by just copying to code, but I'd really like to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 6):

For a good tutorial on `DataBinding` `Joel Johnson` wrote a great one on `CodeProject`

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29054/WPF-Data-Binding-Part-1

Also MSDN has a great tutorial also

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx