# Binding to Parent DataTemplate Property from ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

Say I have this ViewModel and xaml:

```
class MyViewModel
{
    public MyStringValue {get;set;} = "HelloWorld"

    public IList<CustomObject> ChildViewModels{get;set;}
}

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyViewModel}">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ChildViewModels}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyStringValue,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType={x:Type local:MyViewModel}}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</DataTemplate>
```

I keep getting this error message:
"Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor ... "
So basically, I'm trying to bind the parents property container of ItemsControl and it seems like I can't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access parent DataContext from DataTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404707/access-parent-datacontext-from-datatemplate)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RelativeSource` `AncestorType` is something which belongs to a higher level of visual tree (`ItemsControl` here).

Since `MyStringValue` is not a property of `ItemsControl`, you should change `Binding` `Path` as well to point to view model (`DataContext`):

```
{Binding Path=DataContext.MyStringValue, 
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

Comment: wow, that's all it took? I am still new to wpf visual tree concept, and I have tried for hours to get it to work. Thanks a lot! Thanks @Ash! Is there any good tutorial on where I can read up on the visual tree level and how binding works?

Comment: @Cgt, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982834/tutorial-on-advanced-xaml-databinding and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456677/concepts-of-visul-tree-and-logical-tree